# Problem with cookies in httpClient in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies

I create the httpClient in Zend framework to make page requests.
I am trying to add a cookie but it does not seem to work according to the data which I get. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
$httpClient = new HttpClient();
$httpClient->setConfig 
(array(
    'timeout'     => 30, 
    'useragent'   => "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru)Version/10.62",
    'adapter'     => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl', 
    'curloptions' => array 
    (
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT          => 30,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT    => true,
    ),
));


$httpClient->setCookieJar();

$cookie = Zend_Http_Cookie::fromString('abc=1000; ' +
                                       'domain=.abc.ru; ' +
                                       'path=/; ' +
                                       'expires=Wednesday, 28-Feb-12 20:41:22 UTC');
$httpClient->setCookie($cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join strings with plus sign in PHP:

```
'abc=1000; ' +
'domain=.abc.ru; ' +
'path=/; ' +
'expires=Wednesday, 28-Feb-12 20:41:22 UTC'
```

Plus sign is arithmetic operator and this statement simply results in '0'. Use '.' [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).